# Usage of "will" with "if" clause in conditional sentences

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, conditional-constructions, will-would

I have read that "will" should not be used with "if" clause in conditional sentences. However, I feel that below sentence is grammatically correct even though "will" is used with "if" clause. Could you please help clarify same along with good explanation.

> If you will not do it then I will do it myself

**Please note that** I want to know from international competitive exams perspective, so I need grammatically correct answer. Also, all good/additional information you may provide with the answer would be highly and sincerely appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why some people silently come and down vote questions/answers, without providing any reasons. Down voting is of course acceptable and encouraged but without proper explanation it is despicable.

Comment: It is grammatical, but it may not mean what you think it means, that is, it's the verb *will, willed, will·ing, wills*. So you can say *if you will, if he wills* or *she willed that... *. Btw, not the downvoter.

Comment: @LucianSava Thank you for your comment. Even I think that's grammatically correct but I couldn't justify it in context of rule which says that "will" should not be used with "if" clause in conditional sentences...

Answer (score 1):

You should probably take whatever source told you that you can't use "will" in conditional sentences and throw it away ... well, either that or you misunderstood the limits of the "rule".    What about [this famous proverb](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/if-the-mountain-will-not-come-to-muhammad.html) by Francis Bacon, possibly translated from a Turkish saying):

> **If** the mountain **will not** come to Muhammad, then Muhammad must go to the mountain.

Certainly you can use the simple present as well, but "will" is a standard and common syntax used to make conditional statements about the future.

> **If** John Snow **[bends / will bend]** the knee to Daenerys Targaryen, then she **will** make him Warden of the North.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You can please provide some proof (online resource/link) which says that both main and sub clause in conditional sentence can have "will", because resource I read (here in India) says it is grammatically incorrect. I agree with your other answer to my question but not this one, unless you could provide me some proof.