# Why is this sentence not in the subjunctive? "If you draw yourself, how would it turn out?"

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If you draw yourself, how would it turn out?

Someone said it should be like "If you were to draw...", but why? I'm not troubled with the "were to" sentence. I'm just quite confused by the fact that "If you draw..." is wrong.

Comment: I am not sure if "if you draw" is wrong and how authoritative "Someone" is, but "if you were to draw" (or even "if you drew") sounds better because it's the 2nd conditional and the whole situation is hypothetical

Comment: @AndrewTobilko They were just nothing but a person you can find online

Comment: "If you draw yourself, how will it turn out?"

Comment: @KateBunting: OR *If you **drew** yourself, how **would** it turn out?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of "will" with "if" clause in conditional sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/207918/usage-of-will-with-if-clause-in-conditional-sentences)